# monkey testing for react native app for both android and ios

Tags: react-native, monkey-testing

The UI/Application Exerciser Monkey is a command-line tool that sends pseudo-random streams of keystrokes, touches, and gestures to a device. We run it with the Android Debug Bridge (adb) tool and is used to stress-test application and report back errors.

How can we do the same for react native apps of both ios and android.

Comment: We use detox to send presses etc to the device, not sure if it can be used as a stress test tho https://github.com/wix/Detox